# Displaying image from webcam using opencv in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to display images from captured by webcam. However, the variable that stores the captured image is empty. This issue only appears when using a webcam, not when playing videos such as mp4. Is this problem caused by the version of Python? My OpenCV version is 3.4.3 and the Python version is 3.6.5.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from IPython import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as py
%matplotlib inline

def showVideo():
    try:
        print('카메라를 구동합니다.')
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    except:
        print('카메라 구동 실패')
        return
    print(cap.isOpened())
    print(cap.read())
    cap.set(3, 480)
    cap.set(4, 320)

    try:
        while(True):
            # Capture frame-by-frame
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                # Release the Video Device if ret is false
                cap.release()
                # Message to be displayed after releasing the device
                print ("Released Video Resource")
                break
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            # Turn off the axis
            py.axis('off')
            # Title of the window
            py.title("Input Stream")
            # Display the frame
            py.imshow(frame)
            py.show()
            # Display the frame until new frame is available
            display.clear_output(wait=True)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Release the Video Device
        cap.release()
        # Message to be displayed after releasing the device
        print("Released Video Resource")
    pass
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOQW2.jpg)

Comment: I did not find out why, but I checked with another webcam that my code was not wrong. However, my webcam, which did not work on the notebook, works fine in my other apps that I have created using OpenCVsharp. It seems like a interesting problem.

Comment: Ok, I have two different logitech cameras and a Microsoft webcam, and as a result of the test, both of logitech webcams did not work... But Microsoft's webcam worked fine.